RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [64, 128, 3, 3], expected input[1, 64, 124, 328] to have 128 channels, but got 64 channels instead
**have Anyone have any idea regarding this one . **
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "evaluate.py", line 184, in <module>
    args.output_dir, args.file_fmt, args.profile)
  File "evaluate.py", line 82, in evaluate
    output_batch = model(train_batch)
  File "/tools2/opensource/proj/test/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1102, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/tools2/opensource/proj/NeuriCam/model/net.py", line 27, in forward
    return self.model(model_in)
  File "/tools2/opensource/proj/test/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1102, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/tools2/opensource/proj/NeuriCam/model/keyvsrc/net.py", line 151, in forward
    feats = self.propagate(lr_s, feats, key_frame_int)
  File "/tools2/opensource/proj/NeuriCam/model/keyvsrc/net.py", line 95, in propagate
    feats = self.basicvsr_pp.propagate(feats, flows, module)
  File "/tools2/opensource/proj/NeuriCam/model/basicvsr_pp/basicvsr_pp.py", line 252, in propagate
    feat_prop = feat_prop + self.backbone[module_name](feat)
  File "/tools2/opensource/proj/test/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1102, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/tools2/opensource/proj/NeuriCam/model/basicvsr_pp/basicvsr_net.py", line 234, in forward
    return self.main(feat)
  File "/tools2/opensource/proj/test/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1102, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/tools2/opensource/proj/test/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py", line 141, in forward
    input = module(input)
  File "/tools2/opensource/proj/test/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1102, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/tools2/opensource/proj/test/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 446, in forward
    return self._conv_forward(input, self.weight, self.bias)
  File "/tools2/opensource/proj/test/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 443, in _conv_forward
    self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [64, 128, 3, 3], expected input[1, 64, 124, 328] to have 128 channels, but got 64 channels instead

currently i am working on https://github.com/vb000/NeuriCam code and i install all the required library , but getting this error .
and i am using my own dataset .

If I were you, I would make sure that your training data is in the same format as the original dataset (448 x 256 resolution, 7 frames). NeuriCam was trained on samples from the Vimeo-90k dataset. About training (from NeuriCam Github Issues page), Vimeo-90k homepage

[mre] required. please also take the [tour] and review [ask]

hi @BrockBrown , currently i am using pretrain model to test with my own dataset which i created . i divide my dataset into three parts lr_set(160120),hr_set(556720 ) and key_set (2560*1920) , and also go through the issues which posted on NeuriCam github page .
